# DocuSIgn API - Send On Behlaf Of Functionality - Company Name

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am using Docusign API with "Docusign Legacy Authentication". I am using the Send On Behlaf Of (SOBO) functionality. The users have different company names when they set up their accounts. When I am using the API to SOBO of these users the enevlope will always have the company of the API account.

What I need to change in the CReate envelope so that it uses the company of the User I am sending on behalf of.

Thanks
rudrvij

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the branding options will be of help. They enable you to change the appearance and text used in the DocuSign user interface.

[See docs](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/docusign-signing-resource-file(v1.1).pdf).

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: The set up I have is .. I have 2 GROUPS. Lets say GROUP1 and GROUP2. I created 2 brands, BRAND1 and BRAND 2. I associated BRAND1 to GROUP1 and BRAND2 to GROUP2. I added 2 users USER1 and USER2. And put USER1 in GROUP1 and USER2 in GROUP2. When the users use their Docusign account to send their  documents, they are seeing the company (from their profile) and the brand that we created for them. But when I use the API to send the documents using SOBO functionality as these users, it always picks up the API account's company name and the default brand as per the API account.

Comment: Shouldn't SOBO handle this? (Sorry for another comment. It only allows a certain number of characters in comments)

Comment: Try setting the `brandId` field of the base request structure for the Envelopes: create call.